# Generate filtered binary cartesian products

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

#### Problem statement

I'm looking for an efficient way to generate full binary cartesian products
(tables with all combinations of True and False with a certain number of columns),
filtered by certain exclusive conditions. For example, for three columns/bits `n=3` we
would get the full table

```py
df_combs = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*([[True, False]] * n)))
       0      1      2
0   True   True   True
1   True   True  False
2   True  False   True
3   True  False  False
...
```

This is supposed to be filtered by dictionaries defining mutually exclusive
combinations as follows:

```py
mutually_excl = [{0: False, 1: False, 2: True},
                 {0: True, 2: True}]
```

Where the keys denote the columns in the table above. The example would be read
as:

- If 0 is False and 1 is False, 2 can't be True
- If 0 is True, 2 can't be True

Based on these filters, the expected output is:

```py
       0      1      2
1   True   True  False
3   True  False  False
4  False   True   True
5  False   True  False
7  False  False  False
```

**In my use case, the filtered table is multiple orders of magnitude smaller than the full cartesian product (e.g. some 1000 instead of `2**24 (16777216)`).**

Below are my three current solutions, each with their own pros and cons, discussed at the very end.

---

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import wrapt
import time
import operator
import functools

def get_mutually_excl(n, nfilt):  # generate random example filter
    ''' Example: `get_mutually_excl(9, 2)` creates a list of two filters with
    maximum index `n=9` and each filter length between 2 and `int(n/3)`:
    `[{1: True, 2: False}, {3: False, 2: True, 6: False}]` '''
    random.seed(2)
    return [{random.choice(range(n)): random.choice([True, False])
                           for _ in range(random.randint(2, int(n/3)))}
                           for _ in range(nfilt)]

@wrapt.decorator
def timediff(f, _, args, kwargs):
    t = time.perf_counter()
    res = f(*args)
    return res, time.perf_counter() - t
```

---

#### Solution 1: Filter first, then merge.

Expand each single filter entry (e.g. `{0: True, 2: True}`) into a
sub-table with columns corresponding to the indices in this filter entry (`[0, 2]`).
Remove single filtered row from this sub-table (`[True, True]`). Merge with
full table to get the complete list of filtered combinations.

```py
@timediff
def make_df_comb_filt_merge(n, nfilt):

    mutually_excl = get_mutually_excl(n, nfilt)

    # determine missing (unfiltered) columns
    cols_missing = set(range(n)) - set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mutually_excl))

    # complete dataframe of unfiltered columns with column "temp" for full outer merge
    df_comb = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*([[True, False]] * len(cols_missing))),
                            columns=cols_missing).assign(temp=1)

    for filt in mutually_excl:  # loop through individual filters

        # get columns and bool values of this filters as two tuples with same order
        list_col, list_bool = zip(*filt.items())

        # construct dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*([[True, False]] * len(list_col))),
                                columns=list_col)

        # filter remove a *single* row (by definition)
        df = df.loc[df.apply(tuple, axis=1) != list_bool]

        # determine which rows to merge on
        merge_cols = list(set(df.columns) & set(df_comb.columns))
        if not merge_cols:
            merge_cols = ['temp']
            df['temp'] = 1

        # merge with full dataframe
        df_comb = pd.merge(df_comb, df, on=merge_cols)

    df_comb.drop('temp', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df_comb = df_comb[range(n)]
    df_comb = df_comb.sort_values(df_comb.columns.tolist(), ascending=False)

    return df_comb.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

#### Solution 2: Full expansion, then filter

Generate DataFrame for full
cartesian product: The entire thing ends up in memory. Loop through filters
and create a mask for each. Apply each mask to table.

```py
@timediff
def make_df_comb_exp_filt(n, nfilt):

    mutually_excl = get_mutually_excl(n, nfilt)

    # expand all bool combinations into dataframe
    df_comb = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*([[True, False]] * n)),
                           dtype=bool)

    for filt in mutually_excl:

        # generate total filter mask for given excluded combination
        mask = pd.Series(True, index=df_comb.index)
        for col, bool_act in filt.items():
            mask = mask & (df_comb[col] == bool_act)

        # filter dataframe
        df_comb = df_comb.loc[~mask]

    return df_comb.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

#### Solution 3: Filter iterator

Keep the full cartesian product an iterator. Loop while
checking for each row whether it is excluded by any of the filters.

```py
@timediff
def make_df_iter_filt(n, nfilt):

    mutually_excl = get_mutually_excl(n, nfilt)

    # switch to [[(1, 13), (True, False)], [(4, 9), (False, True)], ...]
    mutually_excl_index = [list(zip(*comb.items()))
                                for comb in mutually_excl]

    # create iterator
    combs_iter = itertools.product(*([[True, False]] * n))

    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1024, typed=True)  # small benefit
    def get_getter(list_):
        # Used to access combs_iter row values as indexed by the filter
        return operator.itemgetter(*list_)

    def check_comb(comb_inp, comb_check):
        return get_getter(comb_check[0])(comb_inp) == comb_check[1]

    # loop through the iterator
    # drop row if any of the filter matches
    df_comb = pd.DataFrame([comb_inp for comb_inp in combs_iter
                       if not any(check_comb(comb_inp, comb_check)
                                  for comb_check in mutually_excl_index)])

    return df_comb.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

#### Run examples

```
dict_time = dict.fromkeys(itertools.product(range(16, 23, 2), range(3, 20)))

for n, nfilt in dict_time:
    dict_time[(n, nfilt)] = {'exp_filt': make_df_comb_exp_filt(n, nfilt)[1],
                             'filt_merge': make_df_comb_filt_merge(n, nfilt)[1],
                             'iter_filt': make_df_iter_filt(n, nfilt)[1]}
```

---

#### Analysis

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_time = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_time, orient='index',
                                 ).rename_axis(["n", "nfilt"]
                                 ).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2': 'solution', 0: 'time'})

g = sns.FacetGrid(df_time.query('n in %s' % str([16,18,20,22])),
                  col="n",  hue="solution", sharey=False)
g = (g.map(plt.plot, "nfilt", "time", marker="o").add_legend())
```

[image]

**Solution 3**: The iterator based approach (`comb_iterator`) has dismal running times, but no significant use
of memory. I feel there is room for improvement, though the inevitable loop
likely imposes hard bounds in terms of running time.

**Solution 2**: Expanding the full cartesian product into a DataFrame (`exp_filt`) causes significant
spikes in memory, which I would like to avoid. Running times are ok though.

**Solution 1**: Merging DataFrames created from the individual filters (`filt_merge`) feels like a good
solution for my practical application (note the reduction in running time for greater numbers of filters, which is a result of the smaller `cols_missing` table). Still, this approach is not entirely satisfying:
If a single filter includes all columns, the whole cartesian product (`2**n`)
would end up in memory, making this solution worse than `comb_iterator`.

> Question: Any other ideas? A crazy smart numpy two-liner? Could the iterator based approach be improved somehow?

Comment: Constraint solvers would probably outperform these approaches because they find these solutions by reducing the search space. Maybe take a look at or-tools. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver) an example for SAT.

Comment: @ayhan, I tried (see answer). It's an interesting approach, but not really suitable as a general solution. Thanks for the input. I learned something :)

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) problem, so you should definitely use a solver if the problem is large enough. You could also try https://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Stradivari formulation as a SAT problem definitely makes sense. I don't like the strong dependency on the number of filters of this approach though. Might be that I'm not accessing the solutions properly. Since you know your way around or-tools, maybe you want to have a look at my corresponding [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934609/obtain-list-of-sat-solutions-from-ortools/58935175)... it still lacks an accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try timing the following:

```py
def in_filter(arr, arr_filt, n):
    return ((arr[:, None] >> (n-1-arr_filt[:, 0])) & 1 == arr_filt[:, 1]).all(axis=1)

def bits_to_boolean(arr, n):
    return ((arr[:, None] >> np.arange(n, dtype=arr.dtype)[::-1]) & 1).astype(bool)

@timediff
def recursive_filter(n, nfilt, dtype='uint32'):
    filts = get_mutually_excl(n, nfilt)
    out = np.arange(2**n, dtype=dtype)
    for filt in filts:
        arr_filt = np.array(list(filt.items()))
        out = out[~in_filter(out, arr_filt, n)]
    return bits_to_boolean(out, n)[::-1]
```

It treats the Cartesian binary products as the bits encoded in the range of integers `0..<2**n` and uses vectorised functions to recursively remove numbers that have bit sequences that match the given filters.

The memory efficiency is better than allocating all `[True, False]` Cartesian products as each Boolean would be stored with at least 8 bits each (using 7 bits more than required), but it will use more memory than an iterator-based approach. If you require a solution for large `n`, you could break down this task by allocating and operating on one sub-range at a time. I did have this in my first implementation, but it didn't offer much benefit for `n<=22` and it required the calculation of the size of the output array, which gets complicated when there are overlapping filters.

Comment: This is truly amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @ayhan's comment I implemented an or-tools SAT-based solution. While the idea is great, this really struggles for larger number of binary variables. I suspect this is similar to large IP problems, which ain't no walk in the park either. However, the strong dependency on filter numbers could make this a valid option for certain parameter configurations. But as a general solution I wouldn't use it.

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

class VarArraySolutionCollector(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):

    def __init__(self, variables):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__variables = variables
        self.solution_list = []

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.solution_list.append([self.Value(v) for v in self.__variables])


@timediff
def make_df_comb_sat(n, nfilt):

    mutually_excl = get_mutually_excl(n, nfilt)

    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    make_var_name = 'x{:02d}'.format
    vrs = dict.fromkeys(map(make_var_name, range(n)))
    for var_name in vrs:
        vrs[var_name] = model.NewBoolVar(var_name)

    for filt in mutually_excl:
        list_expr = [vrs[make_var_name(iv)]
                     if not bool_ else getattr(vrs[make_var_name(iv)], 'Not')()
                     for iv, bool_ in filt.items()]
        model.AddBoolOr(list_expr)

    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solution_printer = VarArraySolutionCollector(vrs.values())
    solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)

    df_comb = pd.DataFrame(solution_printer.solution_list).astype(bool)
    df_comb = df_comb.sort_values(df_comb.columns.tolist(), ascending=False)
    df_comb = df_comb.reset_index(drop=True)

    return df_comb
```

[image]